# Creating Dataframes through R For Loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

Fairly new to R, so any guidance is appreciated.

GOAL: I'm trying to create hundreds of dataframes in a short script. They follow a pattern, so I thought a For Loop would suffice, but the `data.frame` function seems to ignore the variable nature of the variable, reading it as it appears. Here's an example:

```
# Defining some dummy variables for the sake of this example
dfTitles <- c("C2000.AMY", "C2000.ACC", "C2001.AMY", "C2001.ACC") 
Copes <- c("Cope1", "Cope2", "Cope3", "Cope4")
Voxels <- c(1:338)

# (Theoretically) creating a separate dataframe for each of the terms in 'dfTitles'   
for (i in dfTitles){
 i <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 338, dimnames = list(Copes, Voxels)))
}

# Trying an alternative method
for (i in 1:length(dfTitles))
 {dfTitles[i] <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 4, ncol = 338, dimnames = list(Copes, Voxels)))}
```

This results in the creation of one dataframe named 'i', in the former, or a list of 4, in the case of the latter. Any ideas? Thank you!

---

PROBABLY UNNECESSARY BACKGROUND INFORMATION: We're using fMRI data to run an analysis which will run correlations across stimuli, brain voxels, brain regions, and participants. We're correlating whole matrices, so separating the values (aka COPEs) into separate dataframes by both Participant ID and Brain Region is going to make the next step much much easier. I already had tried the next step after having loaded and sorted the data into one large dataframe and it was a big pain in the butt.

Comment: Your stated error is not reproducible. Copy and paste only the R commands that you show above into a fresh R session and then edit your post (if required). Thanks. :)

Comment: And fix the spelling of length: `for (i in 1:length(dfTitles) {`

Comment: Sorry about that; also not familiar with posting on StackOverflow. I think that I made the necessary corrections, but please let me know if that formatting is still wacky.

Comment: No problem. :) You've got two answers already. Hopefully one or both of them solves your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rm(list=ls)
dfTitles <- c("C2000.AMY", "C2000.ACC", "C2001.AMY", "C2001.ACC") 
Copes <- c("Cope1", "Cope2", "Cope3", "Cope4")
Voxels <- c(1:3)

# (Theoretically) creating a separate dataframe for each of the terms in 'dfTitles'   
nr <- length(Voxels)
nc <- length(Copes)
N <- length(dfTitles) # Number of data frames, same as length of dfTitles

DF <- vector(N, mode="list")

for (i in 1:N){
  DF[[i]] <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(nr*nc), nrow = nr))
  dimnames(DF[[i]]) <- list(Voxels, Copes)
}

names(DF) <- dfTitles
DF[1:2]
```

---

```
$C2000.AMY
       Cope1     Cope2      Cope3      Cope4
1 -0.8293164 -1.813807 -0.3290645 -0.7730110
2 -1.1965588  1.022871 -0.7764960 -0.3056280
3  0.2536782 -0.365232  2.3949076  0.5672671

$C2000.ACC
       Cope1    Cope2      Cope3      Cope4
1 -0.7505513 1.023325 -0.3110537 -1.4298174
2  1.2807725 1.216997  1.0644983  1.6374749
3  1.0047408 1.385460  0.1527678  0.1576037
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you so much. If you don't mind me asking: Is there a functional difference in removing 'dimnames()' and commanding it separately from 'matrix()'?

Comment: You could easily have used `dimnames` within the `matrix` function like in your original code. I think the reason I separated it was because it didn't work initially. Then I realized that you had the two dimensions around the wrong way and I forgot to put it back.

Comment: Ahh, not a problem! Just wanted to check in. Still getting a sense for good scripting etiquette in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When creating objects in a for loop, they need to be saved somewhere before the next iteration of the loop, or it gets overwritten.

One way to handle that is to create an empty `list` or vector with `c()`before the beginning of your loop, and append the output of each run of the loop.

Another way to handle it is to assign the object to your environment before moving on to the next iteration of the loop.

```
# Defining some dummy variables for the sake of this example
dfTitles <- c("C2000.AMY", "C2000.ACC", "C2001.AMY", "C2001.ACC") 
Copes <- c("Cope1", "Cope2", "Cope3", "Cope4")
Voxels <- c(1:338)

# initialize a list to store the data.frame output
df_list <- list()
for (d in dfTitles) {
  # create data.frame with the dfTitle, and 1 row per Copes observation
  df <- data.frame(dfTitle = d,
                   Copes = Copes)
  # append columns for Voxels
  # setting to NA, can be reassigned later as needed
  for (v in Voxels) {
    df[[paste0("Voxel", v)]] <- NA
  }
  # store df in the list as the 'd'th element
  df_list[[d]] <- df
  # or, assign the object to your environment
  # assign(d, df)
}
# data.frames can be referenced by name
names(df_list)
head(df_list$C2000.AMY)
```

Comment: This script worked really well, as well. Thank you!